# Black space between top display and menu bar Macbook Air M1

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I was try to changes display scale to other options, but still same.
Anyone has issue like this?

[image]

Comment: Have you restored the display scaling to the default?

Comment: how to restore default scaling? I have tried all the display settings